# Inline SVG element with fluid height

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I want to include an inline SVG for a project. I can dump the SVG generated from inkscape into a HTML document and it displays. This is a responsive site, so I want the element to resize fluidly. I keep running into an issue with the height of the SVG element being the height of the document at page load.

```
<div id="svg">
    <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="svg4107">
        <defs id="defs4109"></defs>

        <g transform="translate(0,-552.3622)" id="layer1">
            <path d="m 0,552.3622 500,0 c -505.952711,505.95 -225.92979,225.93 -500,500 z" id="rect3260" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The css is like this:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#svg {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;  
}
```

With images I'm used to setting a `width` as a percentage and `height:auto`, but that doesn't seem to work with inline SVG.

This a simplified example, the production situation is a much more complicated SVG - but this illustrates the issue well. This needs to be a HTML/CSS solution (no Javascript).

[Here is a fiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/QFc88/1/)

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments this seems to be a blink/webkit issue - firefox works fine.

Comment: @GCyrillus - you're right. Webkit/Blink are causing the red to go all the way to the bottom. Grrr. Cross browser issues give me grey hairs

Comment: Well next they will be white, a sign of wisdom , keep going ;)

Comment: It will work once the svg sizing changes are shipped in Chrome/Opera stable, probably in Chrome 36 or so. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308992 for the details. Your example works fine on the trunk of Blink.

Comment: @ErikDahlström Thanks for the info. Ugh though. I love SVG but I feel like it is always trailing where I need it to be. Looks like I'll use a work around (absolute positioning, in my case).